# How to install package on Airgap Fedora IOT with rpm-ostree

Tags: fedora, rpm

I have installed Fedora IOT 38 on an offline server and I'm attempting to install an RPM package. However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
# rpm-ostree install k3s-selinux-1.4-1.coreos.noarch.rpm
Checking out tree 5dcb22f... done
Enabled rpm-md repositories: fedora-cisco-openh264 updates fedora
Updating metadata for 'fedora-cisco-openh264'... done
error: Updating rpm-md repo 'fedora-cisco-openh264': cannot update repo 'fedora-cisco-openh264': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-cisco-openh264-38&arch=x86_64 [Could not resolve host: mirrors.fedoraproject.org]; Last error: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-cisco-openh264-38&arch=x86_64 [Could not resolve host: mirrors.fedoraproject.org]
```

Any hint to bypass this error.

Comment: Does adding `--cache-only` help? I think that should skip that failing metadata update. I haven't tested, so just making this a comment -- but I'll change it to an answer if it works!

Answer (score 0):

I have to disable repos like below and it works

```
sed -i "s/enabled=1/enabled=0" /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo
```